# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "VBORemindersHelper" Vik Booking Plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to use VikBooking on my localhost (XAMPP). After installing and activating the plugin, this error keeps popping up anytime I want to configure or import sample data.
[image]

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "VBORemindersHelper" not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\admin\helpers\widgets\reminders.php:420
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\admin\helpers\admin_widgets.php(336):
> VikBookingAdminWidgetReminders->preload() #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\admin\layouts\sidepanel\multitasking.php(32):
> VikBookingHelperAdminWidgets->getWidgetNames(true) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\libraries\adapter\layout\file.php(135):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\libraries\adapter\layout\helper.php(69):
> JLayoutFile->render(Array) #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\admin\helpers\helper.php(222):
> JLayoutHelper::render('sidepanel.multi...', Array) #5
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\admin\controller.php(5443):
> VikBookingHelper::printHeader('1') #6
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\libraries\adapter\mvc\controller.php(323): VikBookingController->prices() #7
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\libraries\system\body.php(55):
> JController->execute('prices') #8
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\vikbooking.php(196):
> VikBookingBody::process() #9
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(307):
> {closure}('') #10
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(331):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #11
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-includes\plugin.php(474):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #12
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-settings.php(587): do_action('init') #13
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-config.php(96):
> require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #14
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-load.php(50):
> require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #15
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-admin\admin.php(34):
> require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #16 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\wp-content\plugins\vikbooking\admin\helpers\widgets\reminders.php
> on line 420

Answer (score 0):

That used to be a conflict with Windows servers and the new spl autoload register functions introduced with the 1.5.x series of Vik Booking for WordPress. Due to an unescaped backslash (Windows directory separator is a backslash rather than a slash like on Linux/Unix servers) in a regex, the spl autoloader was unable to require the proper class file for one admin widget. Just update the plugin to its latest version and that error will disappear.

In any case, you can contact the tech VikWP team by using the official website. You will get a prompt answer.